# How to call Perl 6 from Java?

Tags: java, raku

Perl 6 regexes/grammars are much better structured, more powerful and readable than Perl 5 or related Perl compatible regexes everywhere, including regexes in Java. I am looking for a way to execute Perl 6 code with that regex/grammar code from Java.

Here is a common example similar I want to do:

```
grammar Calculator {
    token TOP { [ <add> | <sub> ] }
    rule  add { <num> '+' <num> }
    rule  sub { <num> '-' <num> }
    token num { \d+ }
}

class Calculations {
    method TOP ($/) { make $<add> ?? $<add>.made !! $<sub>.made; }
    method add ($/) { make [+] $<num>; }
    method sub ($/) { make [-] $<num>; }
}

say Calculator.parse('2 + 3', actions => Calculations).made;

# OUTPUT: «5␤»
```

Maybe I have to write a `Class` in Perl 6 and have to compile this for JVM Bytecode and then I can call this. Is that a solution or not? Or is that not possible?

Maybe it is too hard to call Perl 6 from Java. There is also another direction. In Perl 6 are lots of Inline modules like Inline::Python, Inline::Perl5 and so on. There is also a way to run java code in Perl 6. Here is an example I found:

```
use java::util::zip::CRC32:from<java>;

my $crc = CRC32.new();
for 'Hello, Java'.encode('utf-8') {
    $crc.'method/update/(B)V'($_);
}
say $crc.getValue();
```

Is this a possible way to start with Perl 6 and bind the mass of Java code then to one project? But how to go back from Java to my Perl 6 code? For Perl 5 I can find the module Inline::Java::Callback but not for Perl 6.

How should I do this in a professional way?

Comment: you really want to avoid that. why do you think you can't write that perl-code in java?

Comment: Why not use JNI to call the Perl interrupter?

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Why not use existing functionalities of Java if you want to run Java code?

Comment: In answer to all three of the above comments. Java regular expressions are based on Perl regular expressions (as are those of pretty much every language in the last 20 years). 
Perl6 has a major rewrite to Regular Expressions making them a lot easier to read and more powerful.

Comment: @NicoHaase Explaining how what's available thru P6 features that *look like* "regexes" (but are easier to write and read and arbitrarily extensible) and *can be referred to* as "regexes" (but are technically of the ["unrestricted grammar"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrestricted_grammar) class, not ["regular expression"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) class) is better than regexes, ANTLR, Canopy and cousins combined would take more than [a book](https://www.apress.com/gb/book/9781484232279). Suffice to say, not all tools are fungible.

Comment: Hi Steffen. On behalf of those trying to keep SO welcoming to newcomers, I apologize. From my perspective your title is clear, and your body details what you want and the problem you have. I'm voting to reopen. Tags attract tag watchers. `perl6` watchers tend to be relatively patient whereas watchers of high traffic tags like `java` tend to jump to conclusions and be relatively unfriendly. Imo TungstenX's JNI interruption is the only useful info. It could be that P6 really needs a JNI based adaptor. In the meanitme, timotimo's answer and its solution will hopefully meet your immediate needs.

Comment: What about wrapping the perl6 Grammar in a web service with Cro?

Comment: @PhilippSander "you really want to avoid that" Is your comment about JNI being recommended over inclusion of bytecode? Some technical expansion of your point would be very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I share the results of my own experimentations and observations, in the hope it will be useful, even if my conclusion is not very positive at the moment. My short answer to the O.P.'s question is: as of may 2019, it is not yet possible.

Now the long answer: the JVM backend support of Perl6 is not yet in a stable, ready-to-use state in latest releases of Rakudo Star:https://rakudo.org/post/announce-rakudo-star-release-2019-03

Anyway, if you want to try your luck, here is an example derived from rakudo-star/nqp/examples (with a small patch, for the original code from rakudo-star-2019.03 won't compile out of the box). Improvements to the original example also include the documentation and basic control of the command line arguments:

```
package examples;
import org.perl6.nqp.runtime.*;
import static org.perl6.nqp.runtime.CallSiteDescriptor.*;
import org.perl6.nqp.sixmodel.*;

public class CallFromJava {
    private GlobalContext g;
    private ThreadContext t;
    private SixModelObject nqpComp;

    private CallFromJava(String bytecode, String hll) {
        g = new GlobalContext();
        t = g.getCurrentThreadContext();

        Ops.loadbytecode(bytecode, t);
        nqpComp = Ops.getcomp(hll, t);
    }

    private SixModelObject eval(String nqp) {
        Ops.invokeDirect(t, Ops.findmethod(nqpComp, "compile", t),
                new CallSiteDescriptor(new byte[] { ARG_OBJ, ARG_STR }, null),
                new Object[] { nqpComp, nqp });

        Ops.invokeDirect(t, Ops.result_o(t.resultFrame()), Ops.emptyCallSite, Ops.emptyArgList);
        return Ops.result_o(t.resultFrame());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.err.printf("usage: java CallFromJava <jarfile> <dialect> <expression>\n");
            System.err.println("<jarfile>: path to nqp.jar or perl6.jar");
            System.err.println("<dialect>: nqp or perl6");
            System.err.println("<expression>: a nqp or perl6 expression");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String jarFile = args[0];
        String dialect = args[1];
        String expression = args[2];
        CallFromJava nqp = new CallFromJava(jarFile, dialect);

        nqp.eval(expression);
    }
}
```

If you take the original code from the Rakudo Star package (version 2019-03 at the time of writing), make sure to apply the following correction (already fixed in the above example):

```
<         Ops.invokeDirect(t, Ops.findmethod(t, nqpComp, "compile"),
---
>         Ops.invokeDirect(t, Ops.findmethod(nqpComp, "compile", t),
```

To build and test the example:

With NQP (Not Quite Perl):

```
cd rakudo-star-yyyy-mm/nqp
javac -cp bin/ examples/CallFromJava.java
java -cp nqp-runtime.jar:3rdparty/asm/asm-4.1.jar:3rdparty/asm/asm-tree-4.1.jar:. examples.CallFromJava nqp.jar nqp 'say(2+2)'
4
```

The problem is that NQP is only a subset of Perl6, not intended for direct use by the Perl6 developer.
With complete Perl6, presumably, one would do something like:

```
export PERL6_PREFIX=/usr/local/perl6 # or whatever your perl6 installation prefix is
cd rakudo-star-yyyy-mm/nqp
javac -cp bin/ examples/CallFromJava.java
java -cp $PERL6_PREFIX/share/nqp/runtime/asm-4.1.jar:$PERL6_PREFIX/share/nqp/runtime/asm-tree-4.1.jar:$PERL6_PREFIX/share/nqp/runtime/nqp-runtime.jar:$PERL6_PREFIX/share/perl6/runtime/rakudo-runtime.jar:$PERL6_PREFIX/share/perl6/runtime/perl6.jar:. examples.CallFromJava $PERL6_PREFIX/share/perl6/runtime/perl6.jar perl6 'say 2 + 2'
```

but I didn't manage to make it work so far

```
Unhandled exception: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: Perl6/Grammar
  in <anon> (src/vm/jvm/ModuleLoader.nqp:76)
  in load_module (src/vm/jvm/ModuleLoader.nqp:58)
  in <anon> (gen/jvm/main.nqp)
```

Answer (score 5):

Compiling perl6 code to JVM bytecode won't immediately help you, I don't think, but there's an "Eval Server" that the test suite uses so that it doesn't have to start a JVM from scratch for each of the many test files in the spec test suite.

You can find the source code to the eval server here, and probably steal a few things from it: https://github.com/perl6/nqp/blob/master/src/vm/jvm/runtime/org/perl6/nqp/tools/EvalServer.java